# Simple way to append a pandas series with same index

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simple way to append a pandas series to another and update its index ? Currently i have two series

```
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import Series

a = Series(randn(5))
b = Series(randn(5))
```

and i can append `b` to `a` by

```
a.append(b)

>>> 0   -0.191924
    1    0.577687
    2    0.332826
    3   -0.975678
    4   -1.536626
    0    0.828700
    1    0.636592
    2    0.376864
    3    0.890187
    4    0.226657
```

but is there a smarter way to make sure that i have a continuous index than

```
a=Series(randn(5))
b=Series(randn(5),index=range(len(a),len(a)+len(b)))
a.append(b)
```

Comment: I advize you to not to do `from ... import *`, and use fully qualified imports, such as `import pandas as pd; pd.Series` and `import numpy as np; np.random.randn`

Comment: @alko It's possible that he do `from numpy.random import randn` and `from pandas import Series`, isn't it?

Comment: @aIKid Either way a reader should guess where from are those imports. For this question I can do it with ease, but it adds some not needed complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `reset_index`:

```
>>> a.append(b).reset_index(drop=True)
0   -0.370406
1    0.963356
2   -0.147239
3   -0.468802
4    0.057374
5   -1.113767
6    1.255247
7    1.207368
8   -0.460326
9   -0.685425
dtype: float64
```

For the sake of justice, [Roman Pekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744834/roman-pekar) method is fastest:

```
>>> timeit('from __main__ import np, pd, a, b; pd.Series(np.concatenate([a,b]))', number = 10000)
0.6133969540821536
>>> timeit('from __main__ import np, pd, a, b; pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True)', number = 10000)
1.020389742271714
>>> timeit('from __main__ import np, pd, a, b; a.append(b).reset_index(drop=True)', number = 10000)
2.2282133623128075
```

Comment: You could also use `reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 4):

you can also use `concat` with `ignore_index=True`:  (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) )

```
pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True)
```

**edit**: my tests with larger `a` and `b`:

```
a = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randn(100000))
b = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randn(100000))

%timeit pd.Series(np.concatenate([a,b]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop

%timeit pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop

%timeit a.append(b).reset_index(drop=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.11 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1 for tests and good solution, looks like `pd.concat` just wrapping `np.concatenate([a,b])`

Answer (score 3):

I think @runnerup answer is the way to go, but you can also create new Series explicitly:

```
>>> pd.Series(np.concatenate([a,b]))
0   -0.200403
1   -0.921215
2   -1.338854
3    1.093929
4   -0.879571
5   -0.810333
6    1.654075
7    0.360978
8   -0.472407
9    0.123393
dtype: float64
```